# How to count checkboxes using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, checkbox

I'm doing a dashboard in Laravel 5.4, and I have a table with several checkboxes. I need to count each time 1 is selected and show the result on the side.

Basically I have to count in real time. And I have 2 lines, I have to count them separately, so I have separate classes

I've tried some things but nothing works.

Thanks in advance for help and ideas on how I can do this, below I leave the code of my checkbox.

```
{!! Form::checkbox('dente[]', $dente->id, null, ['class'=>'denteCheck-up'] ) !!}

{!! Form::checkbox('dente[]', $dente->id, null, ['class'=>'denteCheck-down'] ) !!}
```

In jquery, I've tried +/- this

```
$('.denteCheck-up').change(function(){ });

$('.denteCheck-down').change(function(){ });
```

I'm trying to get the result to appear here

```
<td id="count_dentes_up"></td>

<td id="count_dentes_down"></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `:checked` selector with length function like :

```
  $('#count_dentes_up').text($('.denteCheck-up:checked').length);
  $('#count_dentes_down').text($('.denteCheck-down:checked').length);
```

Code:

```js
$('.denteCheck-up').change(function() {
  $('#count_dentes_up').text($('.denteCheck-up:checked').length);
});

$('.denteCheck-down').change(function() {
  $('#count_dentes_down').text($('.denteCheck-down:checked').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class='denteCheck-up' /> +
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" class='denteCheck-up' /> +
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" class='denteCheck-up' /> +
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" class='denteCheck-up' /> +
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" class='denteCheck-up' /> +
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class='denteCheck-down' /> -
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" class='denteCheck-down' /> -
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" class='denteCheck-down' /> -
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" class='denteCheck-down' /> -
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" class='denteCheck-down' /> -
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="count_dentes_up"></td>
    <td id="count_dentes_down"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```